# resize facebook profile image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, resize, cfimage

Is there any way to resize the profile picture you retreive from the graph api url `https://graph.facebook.com/profileid/picture?type=square`?

I know about the different types you can call. But I need to resize the image server side, stored in a `cfimage` tag, so I can display it with the correct size.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find a way to get to the actual image, because the url doen't get resolved when putting it as source of a cfimage tag.

Comment: If your requirement wasn't to do it on server side, I would have suggested doing it in JS with something like the aeResizeImage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<cfhttp
    url="https://graph.facebook.com/#USER_ID#?type=square&fields=picture"
    method="get"
    getasbinary="yes"
    result="pic">

<cfset img = ImageNew(pic.FileContent)>
<cfif isImage(img)>
    <cfimage action="resize" source="#img#" width="50">
    <cfimage action="writetoBrowser" source="#img#">
<cfelse>
    <img src="Default.png"/>
</cfif>
```

Alternatively, you may want to save the image to disk.

Comment: I added the following code after the resize to be able to put it in a background of a div:
`<cfsavecontent variable="imagePath">
<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#resizedImage#">
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset imagePath = reReplaceNoCase(imagePath, '(<img )(src=")([^""]*)(" alt="".*$)', '\3', 'one')>`

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?type=square&fields=picture` and parse the response. You can use that value directly then, instead of processing the redirect